# How can a character gain additional Wizard Schools?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, wizard

Is there a way for a character to gain access to Wizard School Specialization Powers? Similar in a way to the Eldritch Heritage line? Failing this is there a way for a wizard to gain access to a second School Specialization? Similar to cross-blooded sorcerers?

Edit: Further clarification, this is aiming to do so using standard leveling with a single base class. So no VMC, Mythic Tiers, or similar.

Comment: This question is about gaining School *abilities* in Pathfinder (a feature which doesn't exist in 3.5). The link is about using prohibited *spells* in 3.5. D&D 3.5 attempts a hard prohibit on opposing spells, while pathfinder merely requires additional spell slots. These two question fall hard on the dividing line between D&D and Pathfinder, and as such are not related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## This is possible with the [Ascension](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Ascension) spell.

The Ascension Spell states:

> You imbue a number of creatures with mythic power, granting each of them 1st tier in a mythic path of its choice. The creatures immediately gain the benefits of their chosen paths. Divide the duration evenly among all targets.

This allows us to select the 1st-tier Archmage path ability [Flexible School](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/mythic/mythic-heroes/mythic-paths-paizo-inc/archmage/#TOC-Flexible-School-Ex-) which says:

> Select one wizard arcane school that is not your arcane school. You gain powers from that arcane school, treating your tier as your wizard level for the purposes of these powers. Once you have chosen the arcane school, it cannot be changed. You cannot select an arcane school that is one of your opposition schools.
>
> You must have the arcane school class feature to select this ability. You can choose this ability up to three times, each time selecting another arcane school other than your own.

However, despite this adding another school, you will only be considered level 1 for that school.

---

### There is no other way (that I could find).

The extensive list of [Feats](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/) including [Third-Party](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats) ones, does not include the equivalent of [Eldritch Heritage](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/eldritch-heritage/) for [Arcane Schools](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo-arcane-schools/). Going through the different [classes](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/), including [third party](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/) and [prestige](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/) classes, there was nothing listed that would give two Arcane Schools with a single class.

Comment: Well no way outside of Mythic Tiers, so I suppose that answers the question.